# Как правильно включить сжатие файлов?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Как правильно настроить gzip в Apache?

Для чего нужна эта конструкция - `IfModule mod_deflate.c`?
Что выполняет этот пункт - `BrowserMatch`?

Настройка в `.htaccess`

---

Так?

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

или просто так?

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Для чего нужна эта конструкция - `IfModule mod_deflate.c`?

Проверяет, активирован ли необходимый модуль [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

> Что выполняет этот пункт - `BrowserMatch`

Позволяет задать поведение на основе заголовка user-agent. Используется для установки [`env-переменных`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html), которые использует Apache.

> Как правильно прописать настройки?

Использовать комбинацию из двух процитированных вариантов.
Раз уж в первом варианте делается проверка одного из используемых модулей, пусть делается проверка и для второго.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Данный фрагмент файла `.htaccess` проверяет наличие модуля [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) и, если он доступен, включает сжатие для перечисленных типов файлов. После этого идет проверка наличие модуля [`mod_setenvif`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) и, если он доступен, изменяются параметры сжатия для некоторых браузеров, которые некорректно обрабатывают сжатые файлы.

Comment: Как всегда, качественно и профессионально. Замечательно написан  ответ. Спасибо.